# Pip Install Package Error: Could not install packages due to an OSError

Tags: python, pip

I am getting the following error whenever I try to execute `pip install [any package name]`:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /packages/31/58/d97b7af5302e63bfb3881931fda4aaacbbdcbc31257f983c06703d304c1e/streamlit_chat-0.0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
> (Caused by
> ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x00000228C6A15340>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org
> timed out. (connect timeout=15)'))

I have already tried the following solution that I found on stack, but it doesn't work and I get the same error:

- `pip install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade --proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128 [package name]`
- `pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host    files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org [package name]`

I use a windows system and sublime as my regular coding environment.

Comment: Can you reach that url https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/58/d97b7af5302e63bfb3881931fda4aaacbbdcbc31257f983c06703d304c1e/streamlit_chat-0.0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl in your browser? You can always try to install it by downloading the files directly.

Comment: Can you try install from source https://github.com/AI-Yash/st-chat?

Comment: @EricJin no, I'm not able to access the URL that you've shared. It shows the "This site can’t be reachedfiles.pythonhosted.org took too long to respond. " error message.

Comment: Then I would believe that it might be an issue with your computer or network. Does it work on other computers / other places?

Comment: You are probably going to have to ask your sysops to have the Python domains whitelisted.

Comment: @EricJin thank you so much! Turns out, it was a network issue and once I restarted my network I'm able to use pip install commands on terminal again.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, if you use VPN and try again it will work .

Answer (score 0):

It can happen due network firewall settings, try to connect to other network and then run the command. Worked for me.